# Can't change background color of treeview use Mahapp

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I try to change treeview's color but the color can't fill all of treeview

It's always like this:

[image]

My .xaml

```
<Grid >
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView"
              BorderThickness="0"
              Style="{x:Null}"
              Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
              Background="#38364E"
              Foreground="#38364E"
              Margin="15,15,15,15">

    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

My App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Rodemeyer.Dot2Wpf.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourcesDictionary/ButtonStyle.xaml">
          <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Rodemeyer.Dot2Wpf.ViewModel" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I guess treeview use color style of mahapp and it can't change background color by manual.

Is there anyone know how to fill color to treeview when use mahapp framework.

Comment: What do you have in your `App.xaml` file?

Comment: @mm8 I update App.xaml to my question,there is nothing special in it,only use mahapp style color Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml". I guess it a problem,but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the colours by overriding some resources that are used in the template, e.g.:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView"
          BorderThickness="0"
          Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
          Margin="15,15,15,15">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.ThemeBackground" Color="#38364E" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Text" Color="Red" />
        <!-- mouse over: -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Accent3" Color="Green" />
        <!-- selection: -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Accent" Color="Orange" />
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I try with your code but it's not working, It seem to be it still use mahaap color style. Do you have any idea

Comment: Which version of MahApps.Metro are you using? An old one it seems. Try to upgrade to latest version and modify your `App.xaml` according to the [docs](https://mahapps.com/docs/guides/quick-start).

Comment: Yes, i use the old version mahapp because I try with latest version but can't install it.It always said "System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in MahApps.Metro.dll ...Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors ... The system cannot find the file specified." Why it can't apply on old version.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. It's working now when i change upgrade mahapp to 2.0.1 :) so many thanks and really appreciate for it. :)